# sql server trigger to increment a column when another column decrements

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have a movies table with columns id, title, inventory and I added a column rental_count. I've found solutions online to increment rental_count after the row is updated but would it be possible to increment the rental count only when the inventory gets decremented (when someone rents something)?

Comment: How does that 'inventory' column get updated? Can't you update both columns in the same piece of code? eg: subtract 1 from inventory, add 1 to rentals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Create trigger trigUpdateRentalCount 
   On Movies for Update 
   As
         if Exists( Select * from inserted I
                       Join deleted d
                            On d.pk = i.pk
                    Where i.inventory = d.inventory - 1)

            Update m Set rental_count += 1
            From Movies m 
               join (inserted i Join deleted d 
                        on i.pk = d.Pk
                           and i.inventory = d.inventory - 1)
                  on i.PK = m.PK
```

EDIT to explain trigger.  In any trigger, the user has access to the set of rows being deleted or updated(with the old values) by the sql statement that caused the trigger to fire.  This set can be accessed using the keyword `deleted`.

It also has access to all the rows being inserted or updated (with the new updated values), using the keyword `inserted`.

So if there exists any rows in the deleted table which match to a row in the inserted table, where the new inserted value for inventory is one less than the old value, then, for each such row, you want to update(increment) the `rental_count` field.

The trigger relies on an If Exists statement to determine if any such rows exist in inserted and deleted. Then if there are any, it increments the `rental_count` value in the matching row in the Movies table.

Comment: I didn't downvote it...still playing with your answer. sql server triggers are harder than I thought. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't have time to test this trigger, it seems to be working. But @user2275848, why do you need a trigger for this? Why don't you have a stored procedure to update the table (when someone rents something)?

Comment: Didn't dv, but I believe that you should explain the code. Code only answers are not very clear (as the OP already mentioned).

Comment: You adjusted you answer after receiving the DV's. I'm assuming you know why you got them. I didn't DV you but I can certainly see why the original answer wast DV'd.

Comment: Also you might understand the down-votes if you view the [original version of your answer which, no offense, was terrible](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15980010/1).

Comment: @Aaron,  You're right, I accidently submitted it before I was done... It was at that point totally incomplete, more like psudeocode only - to just describe the logic... And because of that I DID understand the downvotes... I was not complaining that I did not understand them.  I was commenting that still, any downvote should include a reason or at least a comment.

Comment: @user2275848,  I was not addressing my comments to you. For very good reasons, on Stack Overflow it is not possible to determine who submitted a vote, whether it is an upvote or a downvote.

Comment: Because of many vengeful or otherwise tasteless incidents, you will see explanations less and less. In this case you could probably concede that no explanation was necessary.

Comment: @aaron,  yes, I could have...  but, better, perhaps would have been to have made my comment more explicitly general - to have made it more clearly about downvotes w/o comments in general, and less about this specifc. (my), answer and this downvote.

Comment: It's been discussed over and over again on meta, and you just should not expect an explanation. I agree it would be nice, but you're not going to be able to force people to do so, and suggestions to add more rules around this will be shot down with fury.

Comment: @aaron,  Yes, I see.  You may find it surprising, but I have not viisted meta before, but did so today based on your comment.  I see that although in the minority, I am definitely not alone ion my opinion here, and although you are free to use whatever words you choose, I would not use the word "fury" to describe the reaction of the community to the opinion I voiced.  Indeed, if that were the reaction, it would reduce the credibility and persuasiveness of the argument for that position, not improve it.

Comment: Whether or not you feel my description was accurate does not change the fact that it will be shot down and there is no hope in the policies changing.